# Unable to get user field value in event receiver's afterproperties

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, spuser

I have a document library in which there is one field approver (multi - value). There is an event receiver for item updating of the document library that I want to validate user while changing the properties of document.

I want to check if the previous value in user field and new value of user field must be same. To do that I have written following code:

```
string workflowStatus = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem[FieldNames.WorkflowStatus]);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workflowStatus))
{                            
    if (!workflowStatus.Equals(WorkflowHelperData.Constants.Approved))
    {
        if (!General.GeneralMethods.CheckUsersSame(properties.ListItem,properties.AfterProperties,FieldNames.Approver1))
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = "Change in approver field is not allowed";
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        }
    }
}
```

The method to check the users are same or not is as follows:

```
public static bool CheckUsersSame(SPListItem sPListItem, SPItemEventDataCollection sPItemEventDataCollection, string fldName)
{
    SPFieldUserValueCollection userColl = sPListItem[fldName] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
    SPFieldUserValueCollection userColl1 = sPItemEventDataCollection[fldName] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
    if (userColl == userColl1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

After executing the code I am getting `userColl1` to `null`

What should I do to compare new and old field values?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Display Name of the field instead of internal name in before and after properties.

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ef6e1b63-c821-4c6c-b05f-0b1e32ebf073/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-returns-null-value-in-itemupdating-itemupdated-event
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728422/problems-with-beforeproperties-afterproperties-and-listitem-in-itemupdating-of

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found below fix:

```
var userLogin = properties.AfterProperties["UserField"].ToString();
var userFieldValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, userLogin);
var user = web.EnsureUser(userFieldValue.LookupValue);
```